# pthreads waiting thread function to finish before move on

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

First time using pthreads. I've created one class that extends Threads and calling it from another as usual.

here is my code:

```
<?php
class TestThread extends Thread
{
    //
    function __construct($parameters) {
        $this->reverse = $parameters;
    }   

    public function run() {
        try {
            sleep(20);
            // Connecting to mysql database
            $cn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
            INSERT INTO DEVICE_SESSION_ADDRESS (X, Y, Z)
                VALUES (1,2,3)   
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
           //do stuffs
        } 
    }       
}
?>
```

And I call this function from a Rest api method:

```
 function test ($response) {
    require_once 'TestThread.php';
    $rev = new TestThread($response);
    $rev->start();
 }
```

Using Postman to test the rest api, it waits 20 seconds before releasing the call.
The function works, it inserts on database.

What can I do to solve it and call my class TestThread asynchronously ?

Comment: No clue what you are asking

Comment: $rev->start(); is waiting my sleep in the run(). Isn't it should be async ?

Comment: did you use sleep to hang the thread execution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact `pthreads` works perfectly I am convinced the problem has one of these reasons:

1. `pthreads` is not installed. Check `phpinfo()` for `pthreads` section.
2. You call `pthreads` inside an Apache request. In this case `pthreads` is not working as expected. See this note: https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads under **SAPI Support**. You can use `pthreads` only as CLI.

Make sure both points are solved and then it will work!

Comment: Maybe is my understanding about CLI. It is installed and is shown in phpinfo(). My need is: I have one api rest with a method that receives data from some devices (IOT). Then I analyse those information and in some cases I need to dispatch a notification (email, sms, etc). This task can be fire and forget and I'm trying to put the call of those functions in another thread, but the same call from the rest api.

Comment: @GIJOW How do you call your script? In the browser or in the command line with `php script.php`?

Comment: @GIJOW This is what I mean with point 2 in my answer. `pthreads` is **not** working when called from browser. Read the link I provided. Either you solve it without `pthreads` or you adapt your logic and you call your script from command line with `php script.php` - then it will work like a charm.

Comment: @GIJOW `exec` what and where? Without understanding it I would say no. If you want to use `pthreads` the only way is to run it as CLI. As I wrote, you have to reconsider your logic. `pthreads` is not really for beginners because due to the multi-threading there are lot of *traps* which lead to very strange behavior. Try to solve it in the beginning without `pthreads`.

Comment: Using exec without pthreads and call an external script from my webservice. I will play with some possibilities I have.  I'm used with mult-threading but not with php. I thank you a lot for your time and help.